# glitch effect text animation not functioning

Tags: html, css, sass, css-animations, clip-path

I am a beginner in HTML + CSS and I'm trying to copy [this glitch effect animation](https://codepen.io/chasebank/pen/qZNLyx) but codepen uses SCSS files while I'm only using CSS. [Here's my version that is not working properly.](https://codepen.io/jedddddd/pen/JjZmMON) The
"Fast Bug Glitch" animation that makes the div move suddently doesn't work.

HTML
`

```
<section>
      <div class="wrap">
        <div class="creativity-title" data-text="CREATIVITY">CREATIVITY</div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

`

CSS
`

```
.wrap {
  margin-top: 10rem;
  background: black url(/img/Creativity.png) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /*background-attachment: fixed;*/
}

.creativity-title {
  font-family: "Rubik Microbe", cursive;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-shadow: 0px -5px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1),
    0px 0px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), 0px 0px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0),
    0px 0px 15px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), 0px 0px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  animation: noise-anim 3s infinite linear alternate-reverse,
    shift 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate,
    blur 8s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

.creativity-title::after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  left: 3px;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 red;
  top: 0;
  color: transparent;
  background: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip-path: rect(0, 900px, 0, 0);
  animation: noise-anim-2 3s infinite linear alternate-reverse,
    shift 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  z-index: -2;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.glitch:before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  left: 1px;
  text-shadow: -3px 0 cyan;
  top: 0;
  color: transparent;
  background: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip-path: rect(0, 900px, 0, 0);
  animation: noise-anim-3 3s infinite linear alternate-reverse,
    shift 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

/*Animations*/
@keyframes move-up {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(2rem);
  }
}

@keyframes move-down {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(-2rem);
  }
}

@keyframes hue-shift {
  from {
    filter: hue-rotate(0);
  }
  to {
    filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes animate {
  0%,
  10%,
  100% {
    width: 0;
  }
  70%,
  90% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes noise-anim {
  0%,
  40%,
  50%,
  60%,
  90%,
  95%,
  100% {
    text-shadow: 0px -5px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1),
      0px 0px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), 0px 0px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0),
      2px 1px 15px rgba(100, 240, 255, 0), 0px 0px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }

  45%,
  75% {
    text-shadow: 0px -5px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1),
      0px 0px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), 0px 0px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1),
      2px 1px 15px rgba(100, 240, 255, 1), 0px 0px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  }

  97.5% {
    text-shadow: 0px -5px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0),
      0px 0px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), 0px 0px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0),
      2px 1px 4px rgba(255, 100, 100, 1), 0px 0px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes noise-anim-2 {
  0% {
    clip-path: inset(85px, 9999px, 47px, 0);
  }
  5% {
    clip-path: inset(89px, 9999px, 13px, 0);
  }
  10% {
    clip-path: inset(37px, 9999px, 24px, 0);
  }
  15% {
    clip-path: inset(50px, 9999px, 89px, 0);
  }
  20% {
    clip-path: inset(49px, 9999px, 93px, 0);
  }
  25% {
    clip-path: inset(64px, 9999px, 68px, 0);
  }
  30% {
    clip-path: inset(24px, 9999px, 98px, 0);
  }
  35% {
    clip-path: inset(84px, 9999px, 11px, 0);
  }
  40% {
    clip-path: inset(66px, 9999px, 36px, 0);
  }
  45% {
    clip-path: inset(1px, 9999px, 37px, 0);
  }
  50% {
    clip-path: inset(99px, 9999px, 78px, 0);
  }
  55% {
    clip-path: inset(13px, 9999px, 46px, 0);
  }
  60% {
    clip-path: inset(11px, 9999px, 19px, 0);
  }
  65% {
    clip-path: inset(24px, 9999px, 57px, 0);
  }
  70% {
    clip-path: inset(25px, 9999px, 70px, 0);
  }
  75% {
    clip-path: inset(60px, 9999px, 94px, 0);
  }
  80% {
    clip-path: inset(29px, 9999px, 97px, 0);
  }
  85% {
    clip-path: inset(92px, 9999px, 96px, 0);
  }
  90% {
    clip-path: inset(27px, 9999px, 46px, 0);
  }
  95% {
    clip-path: inset(45px, 9999px, 17px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    clip-path: inset(26px, 9999px, 19px, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes noise-anim-3 {
  0% {
    clip-path: inset(14px, 9999px, 73px, 0);
  }
  5% {
    clip-path: inset(89px, 9999px, 25px, 0);
  }
  10% {
    clip-path: inset(23px, 9999px, 57px, 0);
  }
  15% {
    clip-path: inset(46px, 9999px, 3px, 0);
  }
  20% {
    clip-path: inset(18px, 9999px, 49px, 0);
  }
  25% {
    clip-path: inset(80px, 9999px, 19px, 0);
  }
  30% {
    clip-path: inset(7px, 9999px, 61px, 0);
  }
  35% {
    clip-path: inset(98px, 9999px, 92px, 0);
  }
  40% {
    clip-path: inset(43px, 9999px, 43px, 0);
  }
  45% {
    clip-path: inset(94px, 9999px, 95px, 0);
  }
  50% {
    clip-path: inset(88px, 9999px, 65px, 0);
  }
  55% {
    clip-path: inset(38px, 9999px, 78px, 0);
  }
  60% {
    clip-path: inset(60px, 9999px, 43px, 0);
  }
  65% {
    clip-path: inset(6px, 9999px, 89px, 0);
  }
  70% {
    clip-path: inset(8px, 9999px, 41px, 0);
  }
  75% {
    clip-path: inset(42px, 9999px, 52px, 0);
  }
  80% {
    clip-path: inset(34px, 9999px, 34px, 0);
  }
  85% {
    clip-path: inset(21px, 9999px, 90px, 0);
  }
  90% {
    clip-path: inset(60px, 9999px, 70px, 0);
  }
  95% {
    clip-path: inset(4px, 9999px, 59px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    clip-path: inset(8px, 9999px, 49px, 0);
  }
}
```

`

Thus, I decided to modify the SCSS file in my way to make it work in CSS. It's seems that the problem is somewhere where it's written `clip: rect(X, X, X, X);` or the `@keyframes noise-anim-2`

On top of that, I aknowledged that the codepen link used an older version of SCSS and wasn't using `clip-path: rect(X, X, X, X);` but was using `clip: rect(X, X, X, X);` so I changed it in consequence.

I tried my best and I would really like any help for this exercise to improve my skills in CSS,

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.wrap {
  margin-top: 10rem;
  background: black url(/img/Creativity.png) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /*background-attachment: fixed;*/
}

.creativity-title {
  font-family: "Rubik Microbe", cursive;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-shadow: 0px -5px 10px white, 0px 0px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), 0px 0px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), 0px 0px 15px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), 0px 0px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  -webkit-animation: noise-anim-2 3s infinite linear alternate-reverse, shift 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate, blur 8s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
          animation: noise-anim-2 3s infinite linear alternate-reverse, shift 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate, blur 8s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  transform: skewX(0deg);
}
@-webkit-keyframes blur {
  0%,40%, 50%, 60%, 90%, 95%, 100% {
    text-shadow: 0px -5px 10px white, 0px 0px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), 0px 0px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), 2px 1px 15px rgba(100, 240, 255, 0), 0px 0px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
  45%, 75% {
    text-shadow: 0px -5px 10px white, 0px 0px 5px white, 0px 0px 10px white, 2px 1px 15px #64f0ff, 0px 0px 20px white;
  }
  97.5% {
    text-shadow: 0px -5px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), 0px 0px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), 0px 0px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), 2px 1px 4px #ff6464, 0px 0px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes blur {
  0%,40%, 50%, 60%, 90%, 95%, 100% {
    text-shadow: 0px -5px 10px white, 0px 0px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), 0px 0px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), 2px 1px 15px rgba(100, 240, 255, 0), 0px 0px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
  45%, 75% {
    text-shadow: 0px -5px 10px white, 0px 0px 5px white, 0px 0px 10px white, 2px 1px 15px #64f0ff, 0px 0px 20px white;
  }
  97.5% {
    text-shadow: 0px -5px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), 0px 0px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), 0px 0px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), 2px 1px 4px #ff6464, 0px 0px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
}

.creativity-title:after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  left: 3px;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 red;
  top: 0;
  color: transparent;
  background: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip-path: rect(0, 900px, 0, 0);
   -webkit-animation: noise-anim-2 3s infinite linear alternate-reverse, shift 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
          animation: noise-anim-2 3s infinite linear alternate-reverse, shift 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  transform: skewX(0deg);
  z-index: -2;
  opacity: .7;
}

.creativity-title:before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  left: 1px;
  text-shadow: -3px 0 cyan;
  top: 0;
  color: transparent;
  background: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip-path: rect(0, 900px, 0, 0);
  -webkit-animation: noise-anim-2 3s infinite linear alternate-reverse, shift 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
          animation: noise-anim-2 3s infinite linear alternate-reverse, shift 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  transform: skewX(0deg);
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: .8;
}

@keyframes noise-anim {
  0% {
    clip: rect(42px, 9999px, 89px, 0);
  }
  5% {
    clip: rect(52px, 9999px, 3px, 0);
  }
  10% {
    clip: rect(11px, 9999px, 99px, 0);
  }
  15% {
    clip: rect(83px, 9999px, 57px, 0);
  }
  20% {
    clip: rect(27px, 9999px, 34px, 0);
  }
  25% {
    clip: rect(49px, 9999px, 90px, 0);
  }
  30% {
    clip: rect(96px, 9999px, 74px, 0);
  }
  35% {
    clip: rect(11px, 9999px, 97px, 0);
  }
  40% {
    clip: rect(78px, 9999px, 26px, 0);
  }
  45% {
    clip: rect(51px, 9999px, 32px, 0);
  }
  50% {
    clip: rect(26px, 9999px, 2px, 0);
  }
  55% {
    clip: rect(98px, 9999px, 7px, 0);
  }
  60% {
    clip: rect(84px, 9999px, 1px, 0);
  }
  65% {
    clip: rect(91px, 9999px, 47px, 0);
  }
  70% {
    clip: rect(97px, 9999px, 34px, 0);
  }
  75% {
    clip: rect(79px, 9999px, 65px, 0);
  }
  80% {
    clip: rect(32px, 9999px, 62px, 0);
  }
  85% {
    clip: rect(24px, 9999px, 19px, 0);
  }
  90% {
    clip: rect(16px, 9999px, 39px, 0);
  }
  95% {
    clip: rect(30px, 9999px, 79px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    clip: rect(87px, 9999px, 89px, 0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes noise-anim-2 {
  0% {
    clip: rect(25px, 9999px, 35px, 0);
  }
  5% {
    clip: rect(34px, 9999px, 40px, 0);
  }
  10% {
    clip: rect(13px, 9999px, 52px, 0);
  }
  15% {
    clip: rect(30px, 9999px, 48px, 0);
  }
  20% {
    clip: rect(7px, 9999px, 33px, 0);
  }
  25% {
    clip: rect(38px, 9999px, 7px, 0);
  }
  30% {
    clip: rect(1px, 9999px, 15px, 0);
  }
  35% {
    clip: rect(89px, 9999px, 93px, 0);
  }
  40% {
    clip: rect(57px, 9999px, 17px, 0);
  }
  45% {
    clip: rect(33px, 9999px, 48px, 0);
  }
  50% {
    clip: rect(57px, 9999px, 5px, 0);
  }
  55% {
    clip: rect(100px, 9999px, 6px, 0);
  }
  60% {
    clip: rect(2px, 9999px, 92px, 0);
  }
  65% {
    clip: rect(65px, 9999px, 19px, 0);
  }
  70% {
    clip: rect(78px, 9999px, 74px, 0);
  }
  75% {
    clip: rect(46px, 9999px, 10px, 0);
  }
  80% {
    clip: rect(60px, 9999px, 97px, 0);
  }
  85% {
    clip: rect(45px, 9999px, 57px, 0);
  }
  90% {
    clip: rect(65px, 9999px, 87px, 0);
  }
  95% {
    clip: rect(67px, 9999px, 63px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    clip: rect(24px, 9999px, 28px, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes noise-anim-2 {
  0% {
    clip: rect(25px, 9999px, 35px, 0);
  }
  5% {
    clip: rect(34px, 9999px, 40px, 0);
  }
  10% {
    clip: rect(13px, 9999px, 52px, 0);
  }
  15% {
    clip: rect(30px, 9999px, 48px, 0);
  }
  20% {
    clip: rect(7px, 9999px, 33px, 0);
  }
  25% {
    clip: rect(38px, 9999px, 7px, 0);
  }
  30% {
    clip: rect(1px, 9999px, 15px, 0);
  }
  35% {
    clip: rect(89px, 9999px, 93px, 0);
  }
  40% {
    clip: rect(57px, 9999px, 17px, 0);
  }
  45% {
    clip: rect(33px, 9999px, 48px, 0);
  }
  50% {
    clip: rect(57px, 9999px, 5px, 0);
  }
  55% {
    clip: rect(100px, 9999px, 6px, 0);
  }
  60% {
    clip: rect(2px, 9999px, 92px, 0);
  }
  65% {
    clip: rect(65px, 9999px, 19px, 0);
  }
  70% {
    clip: rect(78px, 9999px, 74px, 0);
  }
  75% {
    clip: rect(46px, 9999px, 10px, 0);
  }
  80% {
    clip: rect(60px, 9999px, 97px, 0);
  }
  85% {
    clip: rect(45px, 9999px, 57px, 0);
  }
  90% {
    clip: rect(65px, 9999px, 87px, 0);
  }
  95% {
    clip: rect(67px, 9999px, 63px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    clip: rect(24px, 9999px, 28px, 0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes shift {
  0%,40%, 44%, 58%, 61%, 65%,69%,73%,100% {
    transform: skewX(0deg);
  }
  41% {
    transform: skewX(10deg);
  }
  42% {
    transform: skewX(-10deg);
  }
  59% {
    transform: skewX(40deg) skewY(10deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: skewX(-40deg) skewY(-10deg);
  }
  63% {
    transform: skewX(10deg) skewY(-5deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: skewX(-50deg) skewY(-20deg);
  }
  71% {
    transform: skewX(10deg) skewY(-10deg);
  }
}
@keyframes shift {
  0%,40%, 44%, 58%, 61%, 65%,69%,73%,100% {
    transform: skewX(0deg);
  }
  41% {
    transform: skewX(10deg);
  }
  42% {
    transform: skewX(-10deg);
  }
  59% {
    transform: skewX(40deg) skewY(10deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: skewX(-40deg) skewY(-10deg);
  }
  63% {
    transform: skewX(10deg) skewY(-5deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: skewX(-50deg) skewY(-20deg);
  }
  71% {
    transform: skewX(10deg) skewY(-10deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
      <div class="wrap">
        <div class="creativity-title" data-text="CREATIVITY">CREATIVITY</div>
      </div>
    </section>
```